# Flutter web easy printing

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Due to flutter web exported javascript, we can't print the current web page information.
In the print preview we have blank page, this is not the case with all others website.

My question is simple, is there any way we can get current screen printed with a bluetooth printer or wired using flutter web?

The only thing i found was using a package named printing and i need to rebuild all my page into pdf.

https://pub.dev/packages/printing

Comment: > "The only thing i found was using a package named printing and i need to rebuild all my page into pdf.", Why this solution isn't good for you? I don't think you will find more appropriate solution, Flutter web doesn't generate html code witch is used for classic browser printing.

Comment: By saying "i need to rebuild all my page into pdf" do you say you want to create a pdf and use it as a page in your app? There are packages for this who transform your widgets as pdf document ;)

Comment: I am trying to find a solution to get my page printed without having to recode all the display into a pdf. If i can just grab a widget and print it directly.

Comment: To send something to the printing utility you have to send it as a Universal format like pdf, png, jpeg, etc… The solution here will be to take a screenshot of your screen (there are packages for this) and use this as a pdf, jpeg etc

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this ai_blue_tooth_print - https://pub.dev/packages/ai_blue_tooth_print. It is able to print the flutter web screen straight to the printer. However, this package is not "null safe".